# How can I play a audio clip only when the volume slider value changed?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Linq;

public class Settings : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource[] audioSources;
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
    public TMP_Dropdown resolutionDropdown;
    public TMP_Dropdown qualityDropdown;
    public Text musicText;
    public Text sfxText;
    public Slider[] audioSliders;
    public Toggle fullScreenToggle;

    private Resolution[] resolutions;

    private void Awake()
    {
        audioSources = GetComponents<AudioSource>();

        resolutionDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<int>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("resolutionvalue", resolutionDropdown.value);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));

        qualityDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<int>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("qualityvalue", qualityDropdown.value);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));

        fullScreenToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<bool>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("fullscreen", boolToInt(fullScreenToggle.isOn));
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        qualityDropdown.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("qualityvalue");

        var resolutions = Screen.resolutions.Where(resolution => resolution.refreshRate == 60).ToArray();
        resolutionDropdown.ClearOptions();

        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        int currentResolutionIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height;
            options.Add(option);

            if(resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width &&
                resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
            {
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
            }
        }

        resolutionDropdown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropdown.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("resolutionvalue", currentResolutionIndex);
        resolutionDropdown.RefreshShownValue();

        float musicvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume");
        float sfxvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mainmenusfxvolume");

        musicText.text = musicvolume.ToString();
        sfxText.text = sfxvolume.ToString();
        audioSliders[0].value = musicvolume / 100f;
        audioSliders[1].value = sfxvolume / 100f;

        fullScreenToggle.isOn = intToBool(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("fullscreen", 0));
        
    }

    public void SetResolution(int resolutionIndex)
    {
        if (resolutions != null)
        {
            Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionIndex];
            Screen.SetResolution(resolution.width, resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
        }
    }

    public void SetMusicVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        musicText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));

        //audioMixer.SetFloat("gamemusicvolume", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        //PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("gamemusicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    }

    public void SetSfxVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("mainmenusfxvolume", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        sfxText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("mainmenusfxvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));

        if (!audioSources[1].isPlaying)
            audioSources[1].Play();
    }

    public void SetQuality(int qualityIndex)
    {
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }

    public void SetFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen;        
    }

    int boolToInt(bool val)
    {
        if (val)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    bool intToBool(int val)
    {
        if (val != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

I'm calling this method from ui slider from On Value Changed (single) event in the editor :

```
public void SetSfxVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("mainmenusfxvolume", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        sfxText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("mainmenusfxvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));

        if (!audioSources[1].isPlaying)
            audioSources[1].Play();
    }
```

Screenshot :

[image: sfx volume]

The problem is that when I'm running the game first time and it's starting with the main menu it's playing once the sfx effect audio because this two lines :

```
if (!audioSources[1].isPlaying)
    audioSources[1].Play();
```

The audio source play on awake in the editor is disabled unchecked.
but in the script it's playing it once when the game is running.

What can I do and where to make that it will not play the sfx audio when running the game only when changing the sfx slider volume value ?

Answer (score 1):

In your start function, you change the value of the sliders:

```
audioSliders[0].value = musicvolume / 100f;
audioSliders[1].value = sfxvolume / 100f;
```

Because the value was changed, the sliders fire the `OnValueChanged` event and call the function you told that event to call.

If you don't want to fire the event, you should use [SetValueWithoutNotify](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider.SetValueWithoutNotify.html).

Comment: In the end I did something else much simple. I add a flag in the top : private bool hasChanged = false; then in the Start after changing the sliders value I change the flag to true and then in the function I added to the IF if (!audioSources[1].isPlaying && hasChanged) that's all.  The problem is that it's first making the code in the function then the code in the Start I also checked and it's doing the code in the function before the Awake. Using this flag did the trick.